# Optimizing web-scraper python loop

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I'm scraping articles from a news site on behalf of the owner. I have to keep it to <= 5 requests per second, or ~100k articles in 6 hrs (overnight), but I'm getting ~30k at best.

Using Jupyter notebook, it runs fine @ first, but becomes less and less responsive.  After 6 hrs, the kernel is normally un-interruptable, and I have to restart it.  Since I'm storing each article in-memory, this is a problem.

So **my question is:** is there a more efficient way to do this to reach ~100k articles in 6 hours?

The code is below.  For each valid URL in a Pandas dataframe column, the loop:

1. downloads the webpage
2. extracts  the relevant text
3. cleans out some encoding garbage from the text
4. writes that text to another dataframe column
5. every 2000 articles, it saves the dataframe to a CSV (overwriting the last backup), to handle the eventual crash of the script.

Some ideas I've considered:

1. Write each article to a local SQL server instead of in-mem (speed concerns?)
2. save each article text in a csv with its url, then build a dataframe later
3. delete all "print()" functions and rely solely on logging (my logger config doesn't seem to perform awesome, though--i'm not sure it's logging everything I tell it to)

   ```
   i=0
   #lots of NaNs in the column, hence the subsetting
   for u in unique_urls[unique_urls['unique_suffixes'].isnull() == False]\
   .unique_suffixes.values[:]:

     i = i+1

     if pd.isnull(u): 
         continue

     #save our progress every 2k articles just in case
     if i%2000 == 0:
         unique_urls.to_csv('/backup-article-txt.csv', encoding='utf-8')

     try:
         #pull the data
         html_r = requests.get(u).text

         #the phrase "TX:" indicates start of article 
         #text, so if it's not present, URL must have been bad
         if html_r.find("TX:") == -1: 
             continue

         #capture just the text of the article
         txt = html_r[html_r.find("TX:")+5:]

         #fix encoding/formatting quirks
         txt = txt.replace('\n',' ') 
         txt = txt.replace('[^\x00-\x7F]','')



         #wait 200 ms to spare site's servers
         time.sleep(.2)

         #write our article to our dataframe
         unique_urls.loc[unique_urls.unique_suffixes == u, 'article_text'] = txt


         logging.info("done with url # %s -- %s remaining", i, (total_links-i))


         print "done with url # " + str(i)
         print total_links-i

     except:
         logging.exception("Exception on article # %s, URL: %s", i, u)
         print "ERROR with url # " + str(i)
         continue
   ```

This is the logging config I'm using. I found it on SO, but w/ this particular script it doesn't seem to capture everything.

```
logTime = "{:%d %b-%X}".format(datetime.datetime.now())
logger = logging.getLogger()
fhandler = logging.FileHandler(filename='logTime+'.log', mode='a')
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
fhandler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(fhandler)


logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

eta: some details in response to answers/comments:

- script is only thing running on a 16 GB/ram EC2 instance
- articles are ~100-800 words apiece

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to take an educated guess and say that your script turns your machine into a swap storm as you get around 30k articles, according to your description. I don't see anything in your code where you could easily free up memory using:

```
some_large_container = None
```

Setting something that you know has a large allocation to `None` tells Python's memory manager that it's available for garbage collection. You also might want to explicitly call `gc.collect()`, but I'm not sure that would do you much good.

Alternatives you could consider:

- `sqlite3`: Instead of a remote SQL database, use `sqlite3` as intermediate storage. Exists there does a Python module.
- Keep appending to the CSV checkpoint file.
- Compress your strings with `zlib.compress()`.

Any way that you decide to go, you're probably best off doing the collection as phase 1, constructing the Pandas dataframe as phase 2. Never pays off to be clever by a half. The other half tends to hang you.

Comment: Thanks @ScottM.  re: swaps, the script runs on  16GB AWS EC2, and it's the only thing going--i haven't kept track of memory usage, but is it likely 30k articles would spill into swap? articles being ~100-800 words apiece.  (but either way, appending to some kind of persistent on-disk storage seems like it'd be more efficient than what I'm doing currently)

Comment: Just an educated guess, given that the system becomes totally unresponsive. Sure, 16GB is a lot of RAM for a virtual machine, but that doesn't actually mean that the underlying AWS hardware node is actually giving you 16GB -- hypervisors do tend to overcommit VM RAM, since in the average case, the VM doesn't actually use all of the underlying RAM ("memory ballooning" if memory serves me correctly.)

Comment: Aksi check your process limits, `limit` at bash or zsh prompt. That could also limit, no pun intended, your total memory usage.

Comment: thx Scott-for posterity: i took your advice & stored article results in a list of tuples (url, text, index#).  then, every 1000 iterations, i converted the list of tuples to a DataFrame and wrote a new CSV w/ a unique filename to merge later (felt that was more reliable than appending). i tried cutting out the dataframe altogether, but the python csv module wasn't playing nicely w/ my string encodings.